# pivot_longer two sets of variables into two columns

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot

I want to pivot_longer into two columns based on two sets of variables.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(year = rep(c(2010,2012,2017), 4),
                 party = rep(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), 2),
                 pp1 = rep(c(3,4,5,1,2,6), 2), 
                 pp2 = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 2),
                 pp3 = rep(c(6,2,3,1,5,4), 2),
                 l_pp1 = rep(c(1,2,6,3,4,5), 2), 
                 l_pp2 = rep(c(4,5,6,1,2,3), 2),
                 l_pp3 = rep(c(1,5,4,6,2,3), 2))
```

Data:

```
   year party pp1 pp2 pp3 l_pp1 l_pp2 l_pp3
1  2010     A   3   1   6     1     4     1
2  2012     A   4   2   2     2     5     5
3  2017     A   5   3   3     6     6     4
4  2010     B   1   4   1     3     1     6
5  2012     B   2   5   5     4     2     2
6  2017     B   6   6   4     5     3     3
7  2010     A   3   1   6     1     4     1
8  2012     A   4   2   2     2     5     5
9  2017     A   5   3   3     6     6     4
10 2010     B   1   4   1     3     1     6
11 2012     B   2   5   5     4     2     2
12 2017     B   6   6   4     5     3     3
```

What I need is the following:

```
   year party  area pp l_pp
1  2010     A   1   3   1
2  2012     A   1   4   2
3  2017     A   1   5   6
4  2010     B   1   1   3
5  2012     B   1   2   4
etc.
```

Here pp and l_pp are the same area (pp1 & l_pp1 become pp and l_pp for area 1).

I would think something like this, but values_to can only take size 1.

```
df <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(!c("party", "year"), names_to = "area", values_to = c("pp", "l_pp"))
```

This gets me somehow close, but is not what I am looking for:

```
df <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(!c("party", "year"), names_to = "area", values_to = c("pp"))
```

```
   year party  area pp
1  2010     A   pp1  3
2  2010     A   pp2  1
3  2010     A   pp3  6
4  2010     A l_pp1  1
5  2010     A l_pp2  4
6  2010     A l_pp3  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** Making use of the `.value` sentinel this could be achieved via one pivot_longer like so:

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(year, party), names_to = c(".value", "area"), names_pattern = "^(.*?)(\\d+)$")
#> # A tibble: 36 × 5
#>     year party area     pp  l_pp
#>    <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  2010 A     1         3     1
#>  2  2010 A     2         1     4
#>  3  2010 A     3         6     1
#>  4  2012 A     1         4     2
#>  5  2012 A     2         2     5
#>  6  2012 A     3         2     5
#>  7  2017 A     1         5     6
#>  8  2017 A     2         3     6
#>  9  2017 A     3         3     4
#> 10  2010 B     1         1     3
#> # … with 26 more rows
```

As a second option the same result could be achieved via an additional `pivot_wider` like so, where as an intermediate step one has to add an id column to uniquely identify the rows in the data:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(!c(year, party), names_to = c("var", "area"), names_pattern = "(.*)(\\d)") %>% 
  group_by(year, party, area, var) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 36 x 6
#>     year party area     id    pp  l_pp
#>    <dbl> <chr> <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  2010 A     1         1     3     1
#>  2  2010 A     2         1     1     4
#>  3  2010 A     3         1     6     1
#>  4  2012 A     1         1     4     2
#>  5  2012 A     2         1     2     5
#>  6  2012 A     3         1     2     5
#>  7  2017 A     1         1     5     6
#>  8  2017 A     2         1     3     6
#>  9  2017 A     3         1     3     4
#> 10  2010 B     1         1     1     3
#> # … with 26 more rows
```